# Moving apps to SD

Tags: external-sd, app2sd

I recently had my first Android device (rooted), but it has only 8GB.

I love playing games of all sort. So, I found an option in the apps menu that moves the apps to SD. Firstly, I had 4.97GB free, but after I moved my app, it had the same storage free!
I searched on internet and learnt that it doesn't move app to the EXTERNAL SD, but on the internal SD, which has only 8GB (the system).

So is there a way to move apps on external SD? Thank you!

EDIT: Finally I found Directory Bind that does what I want! http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1410262

Comment: Did you figure something out? Did one of the apps I suggested below work?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I found http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1410262, it works well !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Link to SD Card app ? Try this app I am using it and it actually move apps to external SD. If you can't get your solution from Link2 SD than try Lucky Patcher.

- Just install that app in your mobile.
- Open that app, write the app name and select the app from the listings
- On next page, Tap on move to SD.

**Original Source:**

http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-1768697/move-apps-card-android.html

Answer (score 0):

I think an app called Titanium Backup has a feature like that. It is also full of other features. It is a must have for any rooted android. Practically why I rooted in the first place.

Comment: No, it doesn't do what I want. It moves data from system to internal SD, which is in fact the internal storage. I want to move data from the internal storage to my SD card. (which has 32Go, it is a bit bigger than 8Go ^^')

Comment: @tib20 GL to SD https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slf.ListglApp&hl=en

Comment: @tib20 ICS SD Binder might help. You didn't mention your phone make and model. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.qbanin.binder&hl=en

Comment: @fredsbend I'm surprised you're using Go instead of GB (gigabytes). What does Go mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm french and Go stands for GigaOctet. It's the same as GB ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Samsung Galaxy SII Plus,

i found a solution on youtube: here is the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8PyqCOpERA

But notice that not all games can be moved, following that video will show you jut how to do it for some games like MXOFFROAD and SHADOWGUN.

I find It really disappointing to save Apps only in the Internal Memory, it's a dump idea..But in some old Android Versions have the possibility to move Apps to the External SdCard.

I hope this will help you a little bit..better than nothing.Thanks to DirectoryBind App, I could move two games until now, 2XL MXOFFROAD AND CSR RACING.

Note: You will not find DirectoryBind App on GooglePlay, to download it, look in the Video Description you will find the download link. Connect your mobile via USB cable to a computer and copy and past the downloaded App in Phone's memory. Eject your Phone. Go to GooglePlay and search for Apk Installer.Download this latest and open it to search for DirectoryBand App, while found install it and follow the video on youtube.

GoodLuck.

Comment: Would you mind to rephrase the solution found on youtube a little? External content tends to become inaccessible over time and this answer will not be helpful any more...